# My divs are stacking on top of each other when I try to float items

Tags: html, css

I'm a super-noobie at CSS and I've made some boxes for practicing positioning items on a page. Sadly, I've already run into a problem! I want to put boxes 1 and 2 next to each other on one line, and boxes 3 and 4 on the next line. I was trying to use `float: left` to make box 2 go up to box 1, but things are just overlapping.

**Would post images if I could.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxprac.css">
    <title>Box Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box1">
      <h1>Box One</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <h1>Box Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
      <h1>Box Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
      <h1>Box Four</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

STYLE

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#box1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  clear: left;
}

#box2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#box3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
}

#box4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

I can manage to line up boxes 2, 3, and 4 on the second line with the float left property; however, if it's not on all three boxes then they stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `float: left` on all four boxes, and add `clear: left` to the third one:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#box1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#box2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#box3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

#box4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
    <div id="box1">
      <h1>Box One</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <h1>Box Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
      <h1>Box Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
      <h1>Box Four</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Alright, I tried that. Box 1 does line up with Box 2 now; however now Box 3 is on a line by itself and the text of Box 4 is on the line under it and the actual border for Box 4 is stacked some way on top of Box 1. http://i.imgur.com/nYSqodD.jpg

Comment: then you did something different, but I can't see what you did, so I can't see the error... It sounds as if you forgot to close an HTML tag somewhere, but I can't really tell without seeing it. (I mean the code)

Comment: Actually from your image I guess you didn't put `float: left`on the fourth box (check also for syntax errors like semicolons at the end of each line etc.)

Comment: It didn't seem that I left any semi-colons out on the original code, but somehow it's miraculously working. I got the boxes to line up! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the idea behind solving this. The best way is to `wrap` each group of boxes in a `div`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.boxes {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  }
#box1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#box2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#box3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#box4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 50px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxprac.css">
    <title>Box Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div id="box1">
      <p>Box One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <p>Box Two</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
    <div id="box3">
      <p>Box Three</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
      <p>Box Four</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```